# How to generate certificate.pem from Plesk for BIMI

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, certificate, plesk

I would like to add a BIMI record. I use a shared hosting and already using Let's encrypt for SSL.

On google I found this tutorial: https://support.google.com/a/answer/10911321?hl=en, but it doesn't specify where to get the certificate.pem.

How to get / generate the certificate.pem in Plesk?

Comment: Described here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/10911028